# Handlebars Js Not Loading my Content

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I am trying to parse some json with Handlebars on my website. I don't get any errors but also don't get any content. I've developed my own rest point to return a json response and I think my problem might be there somewhere, but you can see the response in the code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Czdxh

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var raw_template = $('#post-template').html();
  // Compile that into an handlebars template
  var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
  // Retrieve the placeHolder where the Posts will be displayed 
  var placeHolder = $("#all-posts");
  // Fetch all Blog Posts data from server in JSON
     $.getJSON("https://instapi-motleydev.rhcloud.com/liked",function(data){

         $.each(data,function(index,element){
      // Generate the HTML for each post
      var html = template(element);
      // Render the posts into the page
      placeHolder.append(html);
    });
  });

});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was getting an array response from the server and needed to adapt my template to include the {#each this} syntax. Also switched my getJSON to a simple get and looped over the reaction that way and tossed the $.each handler.